# Supply chain SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having issues with my SQL code.

I want to display the total count of stores that correspond with a certain Distribution Center/ WH. I want both to be tied to a certain item.

For example: I have one WH that gave a certain item to 50 stores. I want the query to tell me if I give it the item# and WH# it will give me the amount of stores that received that item.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_STORES
FROM
    (SELECT 
         a.WH_i, a.STORE_i
     FROM  
         WH a, STORES b
     WHERE 
         a.item_i = 2201
         AND a.WH_i IN (10) 
     GROUP BY 
         a.WH_i, B.STORE_i
     HAVING 
         COUNT(a.item_i) = 1) a;
```

Table WH has the warehouse numbers and item numbers and store has the store numbers.

I am new to SQL so I am not 100% confident with joins just yet. Any help is greatly appreciated though!

EDIT: I tried joining the two tables without actually using the JOIN clause and it is still not giving proper results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_STORES
FROM( 
  SELECT a.WH_i, b.STORE_i
  FROM  WH a, STORES b
  WHERE a.item_i = b.sku_i
  AND a.stock_i = b.stock_i
  AND a.item_i = 2201
  AND a.WH_i IN (10) 
  GROUP BY a.WH_i, B.STORE_i
  HAVING COUNT(a.item_i) = 1
 )a;
```

Comment: You're not currently joining `a` and `b` to each other in any manner. This query will result in a cartesian product and very high counts.

Comment: How do I join a and b together? I am still new to sql

Comment: You have to have a column common to both tables to join on.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: [Sample data + expected results](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help too. Probably the underlying issue is not specific to supply chains, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want the count of stores so just pull stores in your subquery.

```
SELECT COUNT(STORE_i) AS TOTAL_STORES
FROM( 
  SELECT b.STORE_i
  FROM  WH a
      JOIN STORES b
      ON a.item_i = b.sku_i
      AND a.stock_i = b.stock_i
  WHERE 
      a.item_i = 2201
      AND a.WH_i = 10
  GROUP BY b.STORE_i
  HAVING COUNT(a.item_i) = 1
 ) a;
```

Comment: I tried using this and it works for the most part but it still gives me a TOTAL_SALES value of 0 for some reason when I know that is not the case.

Comment: You may have some values you're not expecting in `WH`.

Comment: Could it not be working if more than two columns are the same in both tables? I have about 5 columns that are the same in each. I just didn't list cause I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: Well that shouldn't be the cause the problem you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.WH_i, a.item_i, count(DISTINCT b.store_i)
FROM WH a
JOIN STORES b
ON a.item_i = b.sku_i
GROUP BY a.WH_i, a.item_i
```

Comment: The table stores actually has something in common with WH, WH has item_I while stores has sku_i which are the same thing. Also, they have stock_i in the same table which is just the amount of inventory they have on hand.  I hope this helps

Comment: Okay, that's perfect. I edited my answer to include the information you've just provided. Can you give the above code a try and see if it gets the result you're looking for? If you want to narrow down the results to specific item_i and/or WH_i, then you can add a WHERE clause just before the GRUP BY clause, which would read something like WHERE item_i = 2201 AND WH_i = 10